# Layout custom forms using Panels

Tags: 7, forms, panels

Can I use the [Panels](https://drupal.org/project/panels) module to layout a custom form?

I've created a custom form and I'm loading it in a menu callback using a function like this:

```
function _MODULE_menu_callback_function() {
  return drupal_get_form('_my_custom_form');
}
```

My ultimate goal is to use the Panels UI to rearrange the form fields into different panes so that I can easily mix in other elements.

I tried to use [Page Manager: Existing Pages](https://drupal.org/project/pm_existing_pages) to accomplish this, but it simply brings the form in as a whole.  I cannot break the fields apart into different panes using this module.

Is this possible with Panels?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create fieldable entity type to make form as you wish and make your custom form by adding fields to it. Than this fields will accessible in page manager UI.